# Possible to have a noteboard webpart in a teamsite that doesn't show notes on mysite?

Tags: team-sites

I would like to add the noteboard webpart to a teamsite, but I don't want the notes posted on this board to be visible on mysite. Is it possible to turn off/block this connection for this specific webpart? Is there an easy way?

Or is there an alternative noteboard style webpart?

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. The Noteboard webpart saves its notes to the User Profile of the current user and hence this is displayed on the news feed on the personal site (MySite) of the user.

You will have to look into a custom solution or a third party solution to fulfill your needs.